# Inclusion, pullback of differential form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, spherical-coordinates

Let $\omega=x\,dy\wedge dz +y\,dz\wedge dx+z\,dx\wedge dy$ or in spherical coordinates (unless I had made some mistake) $\omega=r^3\cos \theta\, d\phi\wedge d\theta$. Now I want to find $i^*\omega$ where $i:S\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is inclusion of unit sphere, using $\phi$ and $\theta$. It seems quite easy but I'm not sure how to interprete $i$ and how  to use it in $i^* \omega$. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $S$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $S$ is given by the equation $r = 1$ in spherical coordinates. Therefore,

$$i^*\omega = i^*(r^3\cos\theta d\phi\wedge d\theta) = 1^3\cos\theta d\phi\wedge d\theta = \cos\theta d\phi\wedge d\theta.$$

Comment: What with $\cos\theta$ in $\omega$?

Comment: Sorry. I've fixed it now.