# Integration of differential form inclusion of $S^2$

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Take [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565848/inclusion-pullback-of-differential-form). We have the natural inclusion $i : S^2 \rightarrow R^3$ and the differential form: $\omega = x dy \wedge dx + y dz \wedge dx + z dx \wedge dy $. How can we say that that the pullback of the inclusion $i^*\omega = cos(\theta)d\phi \wedge d\theta $?

That is an expression on local coordinates!

I guess I am in general confused about when we are "allowed" to use coordinate expressions for a coordinate independent object.

We defined the Integral of a differential form
$\omega: TM \rightarrow R$ over a measurable subset $A \subseteq M$ with charts $(U_\alpha,x_{\alpha}) $

via partition of Unity $ \{ \phi_\alpha \}  _{\alpha \in I}$ s.t. $ \omega= \sum_{\alpha \in I} \phi_{\alpha} \omega $ in the following way:
$$ \int_A \omega = \sum_{\alpha \in I} \int_{x_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha} \cap A)} f_{\alpha} dm $$
where $f_\alpha$ is the unique function s.t. $\phi_{\alpha} \omega = x_\alpha ^*(f_\alpha dx^1\wedge ... \wedge dx^n) $

I think that in the above example
$$\int_{S^2} i^* \omega = \int_{x(S^2)}cos(\theta)d\phi \wedge d\theta  =  \int_{(0,2\pi) \times (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})}cos(\theta)d\phi  d\theta = 4 \pi$$

But how can I rigorously say that? Or just do it?...

**EDIT**
I bascially want to know how to show the first equality in the last line? (I know how to compute it)

Comment: The last equality you wrote is true since $(\phi,\theta)$ is a parametrization of the sphere on a subset of full measure. The remainder is of measure zero and does not contribute to the integral.

Comment: But how do I get the $cos(\theta) d\phi \wedge d\theta$ in the integral? I know how to compute it, but I think I can't just say that $ i^* \omega = cos(\theta )d\phi \wedge d\theta$. But then how do I show the first equality in the last line?

Comment: Basically the same way as in the link you provided: the change of coordinates on $\Bbb R^3$ given by the polar coordinates $(r,\phi,\theta)$ allows  on to write $\omega$ in the new coordinates system as $r^3 \cos \theta d\phi\wedge d\theta$. Now, pull-back this on the unit sphere $r=1$.

Comment: But that's exactly my confusion! This is a coordinate expression and thus not actually $i^* \omega$, but maybe $x_*(i^* \omega)$ ? But then again, just claim that's true or can I how to argue that this is true?

Comment: Write the inclusion $i\colon S^2 \to \Bbb R^3$. It is given by $x\mapsto x$. Choose coordinates $(\phi,\theta)$ on the left, and $(r,\phi,\theta)$ on the right. What is the expression of the inclusion in these coordinates? Now, express $\omega$ on the right in the coordinates, and look at $i^*\omega$ as an intrinsic object on the left. Now, express this in coordinates. You will see that setting $r=1$ is a rigorous shortcut.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! But, when can I just go to coordinates? And how do I denote that? Like that?: Let $x: S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $ be a chart of $S^2$ and $\tilde{x}: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a chart of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then is the inclusion in local coordinates given by: $i_C = \tilde{x} \circ i \circ x^{-1}: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $. Can I then just say $$ \int_{S^2} i^* \omega = \int_{x(S^2)} i_C^* \omega_C $$ where $\omega_C$ is the coordinate form of $\omega$ that coincides here with $\omega$, since $\tilde{x}$ is the identity here? Or is it

Comment: not acutally true, that we can't give an expression for $\omega$, but always implicitly mean $\omega_C$ since $\mathbb{R}^3 $ is also a manifold (thus we have to choose cooridnates first)?

Comment: Sorry $\tilde{x}$ is not the identity here, and thus $\omega _C $not the same as $ \omega$

Comment: I think I don't get what you don't get. You don't have to take any chart, just take the one given by your favourite coordinates, here the spherical coordinates.

Comment: Yes exactly, we can just take our favourite coordinates x and $\tilde{x}$, but we have to do that! And then the equality of the two integrals, stated in my last comment should hold, right?

Comment: Do you understand why the differential form $dx$ is **equal** to the differential form $\cos\theta \cos \phi dr - r\sin\theta\cos \phi d\theta - r\cos\theta\sin\phi d\phi$ on $\Bbb R^3 \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: Yes, that’s just a change of Basis (using chain rule). 
My problem is that the claim $i^* \omega = cos(\theta) d\phi \wedge d\theta $ can’t be correct since $d\theta$ und $d\phi$ don’t live in $S^2$, but in local coordinates. I want to know how to formally go from the manifold to local coordinates.

Comment: $(\theta,\phi)$ are local coordinate on the sphere, and $d\theta$ and $d\phi$ are local $1$-forms on the sphere!

Comment: Thank you! That helped me! But then the last equality isn’t clear to me. It should be: $$\int_{S^2} i^* \omega = \int_{S^2}cos(\theta)d\phi \wedge d\theta  =  \int_{(0,2\pi) \times (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}) = x(S^2)}cos(\theta)d\phi  d\theta $$   According to our integral definition, the following should hold: $cos(\theta) d\phi \wedge d\theta = x^*(cos(x)dy \wedge dx) $, where the $x^*$ means the pull back of the coordinate map and the x and y live in that coordinate space.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95186/788724) answer your question?

Comment: My problem isn't the computation or how to evaluate the integral (which makes sense to me). My problem is how that evaluation comes out of the definition. where the last equality of my last comment comes from the definition or rather why the pullback $x^*(cos(x)dy \wedge dx) = cos(\theta) d\phi \wedge d\theta$

Comment: Also that makes sense to me, but I just want to know how to rigorously get that from the definitions of the pull back. Or do we just say that this is obvious?

Comment: The coordinates $(\theta,\phi)$ have to be understood as functions of the point $p\in S^2$, and $d\theta$ and $d\phi$ as differential forms of degree 1. The map $x \colon p \mapsto (\theta(p),\phi(p)) $ is a diffeomorphism from where it is defined to $(0,2\pi)\times (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Here, $x^* (i^* \omega) = \cos\theta$, the function of $\theta$, on $(0,2\pi)\times (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: $ x: S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $i: S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. Thus $i^* \omega$ lives in $S^2$. I though the pullback $x^*(i^* \omega) $ doesn't make sese then, because it only makes sense to pull back forms that live in $\mathbb{R}^2$. To integrate we need to find a form living in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose pull back is our form on $S^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof.

Consider $p\colon (0,2\pi) \times (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}) \to \Bbb S^2$ the parametrization given by $p(\theta,\phi) = (\cos\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$. First, note that $p^*(i^*\omega)= (i\circ p)^* \omega$, and therefore,
\begin{align}
p^*(i^*\omega) &= p^*i^*(x dy\wedge dy + y dz\wedge dx + z dx \wedge dy)\\
&=  (x(i\circ p)) (i\circ p)^* (dy\wedge dz) + (y(i\circ p)) (i\circ p)^*(dz \wedge dx) + (z(i\circ p)) (i\circ p)^* (dw\wedge dy)
\end{align}
Now, use the fact that the pullback and the wedge product commute; so that
\begin{align}
(i\circ p)^* (dy\wedge dz) &= ((i\circ p)^*dy)\wedge((i\circ p)^* dz)\\
(i\circ p)^* (dz\wedge dx) &= ((i\circ p)^*dz)\wedge((i\circ p)^* dx)\\
(i\circ p)^* (dx\wedge dz) &= ((i\circ p)^*dx)\wedge((i\circ p)^* dy)
\end{align}
Note that
\begin{align}
(x(i\circ p)) &= x\circ i \circ p = \cos\theta\cos\phi\\
(y(i\circ p)) &= y\circ i \circ p = \sin\theta\cos\phi\\
(z(i\circ p)) &= z\circ i \circ p = \sin\phi
\end{align}
and now, use the chain rule in order to show that
\begin{align}
(i\circ p)^*dx &= dx \circ d(i\circ p) = d (x\circ i \circ p) = d(\cos\theta\cos\phi)\\
(i\circ p)^*dy &= dy \circ d(i\circ p) = d (y\circ i \circ p) = d(\sin\theta\cos \phi)\\
(i\circ p)^*dz &= dz \circ d(i\circ p) = d (z\circ i \circ p) = d(\sin\phi)
\end{align}
Expand these equalities, *e.g* $d(\cos\theta \cos \phi) = -\sin\theta \cos \phi d\theta - \cos \theta \sin \phi d\phi$.
Gluing these equalities all together and using the fact that $\cos^2 + \sin^2 = 1$, you should find
$$
p^*(i^*\omega) = \cos\phi d\theta \wedge d\phi
$$
Since the complementary of $Im(p)$ in $\Bbb S^2$ has measure zero, and since $p$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image, it follows that
\begin{align}
\int_{\Bbb S^2} i^* \omega &= \int_{Im(p)} i^*\omega \\
&= \int_{(0,2\pi)\times (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})}p^*(i^* \omega)\\
&= \int_{(0,2\pi)\times (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})} \cos \phi d\theta\wedge d\phi\\
&:= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos \phi d\theta d\phi
\end{align}
The last equality being true by **definition** of the integral of the top form $\cos\phi d\theta \wedge d\phi$ in the oriented manifold $(0,2\pi)\times (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Comment: Thank you so much! That made it clear!